# In mySql, how can I ask: select this row from table 1 where x = column in table 2 or no rows in table 2

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, compare

Could not find an answer here, only pieces...
Specifically:

```
Table 1
  id, product

Table 2
  id, keyword, value
```

Given a list of keywords and values (array, json, anything), such as:

```
  year=1920
    model=R45-2
    color=green
```

For a given row in Table 1 matched by id, there may be no row in Table 2, or any number of them. Each will have a different keyword & value.

I need to return rows from Table 1 where there is either NO matching pair in Table 2, or EVERY keyword from my list matches its corresponding value in Table 2.

I'm aware that I can use IN, JOINS and sub-queries, but every solution I think of looks HORRIBLE (and may be a speed-hog). What is the fast, efficient, clean-reading way to do this? Remember, the 'list' provided may have none, one or n entries; Table 2 as well. NO match at all for a given keyword in Table 2 should allow Table 1 row through, or all in list matching; any keyword/value mismatch should invalidate that row from Table 1.

Good luck.

Comment: you should reverse your way of thinking about joins.  They aren't slow, they're generally faster than anything else, and if they're not fast enough for your case, it's probably the data schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `group by` and `having` can do what you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.product
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 using (id)
group by t1.id, t1.product
having not max(
      (t2.keyword = 'year'  and t2.value <> '1920')
    + (t2.keyword = 'model' and t2.value <> 'R45-2')
    + (t2.keyword = 'color' and t2.value <> 'green')
) <=> 1
```

Comment: Hm, my head hurts.

Comment: Appreciate fast answer. Not familiar will all of it. First, why the GROUP? Because the JOIN will return multiple rows?

Comment: ...and MY head hurts. Seems the only way to do this is a double-negative?? The <=> is for filtering NULLS but the NOT reverses that to allow them? And the + between key/values makes it a _whole_ true/false??

Comment: ...so you're making the key/value comparisons into one boolean that allows for NULLS? If so, then why the MAX..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked; seems simplest: (relevant sections only)

User wants color=green, size=small. So, number of terms is two.

SELECT ... LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemID, COUNT(itemID) AS filterCount FROM auctionExtras E WHERE (E.key = 'color' AND E.value = 'green') OR (E.key = 'size' AND E.value = 'small') [OR term clause n] GROUP BY itemID) as F on (...) WHERE (filterCount = [number of terms])

I THINK fairly quick on the subquery as ON restricts to an ID from the main query, and 'keys' in the joined file won't be evaluated at all unless you add them in to the WHERE. Everything indexed, and I doubt anyone will ever use more than five key/value pairs.